# Attach a pop-up menu to a self-defined event in GLUT?

Tags: opengl, glut

I know that with GLUT, I can create a Pop-up Menu with `glutCreateMenu`, `glutAddMenuEntry`, `glutAttachMenu`.
And there are three events can be used with glutAttachMenu -- "GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON, GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON, GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON".

However, I want this Pop-up menu show when some other event happens, such as *double-click* (assuming that I have written a function *DoubleClick()* which will return true if there is a double-click).

How can I implement this?

Comment: By ditching GLUT. GLUT is not meant to be used for anything more complex.

Comment: For creating menu's i use QT.

Comment: well, learned a lot, thanks all.